# Mocking and unit testing Microsoft Graph API to get users list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK in my project to call graph API which returns a list of users in

I am trying to mock a call to the microsoft graph api and return a list of users that I can use to assert. I am not really getting how to use the setup method to get an object to assert on. Currently getting an null references object error.

> Interface:

```
public Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync();
```

> GetUsersAsync() method calling the API:

```
    public Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        return this.appClient.Users
            .Request(this.queryOptions)
            .Select(@$"
            Id,
            DisplayName,
            GivenName,
            Surname,
            Mail,
            OtherMails,
            CompanyName,
            .OrderBy("DisplayName")
            .GetAsync();
    }
```

> MS Test: Unit testing:

```
public Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        return this.appClient.Users
            .Request(this.queryOptions)
            .Select(@$"
            Id,
            DisplayName,
            GivenName,
            Surname,
            Mail,
            OtherMails,
            CompanyName,"
            .OrderBy("DisplayName")
            .GetAsync();
    }

    
      [TestMethod]
    public void GetUsersAsyncSuccess()
    {
        var mockAuthProvider = new Mock<IAuthenticationProvider>();
        var mockHttpProvider = new Mock<IHttpProvider>();
        var mockGraphClient = new Mock<GraphServiceClient>(mockAuthProvider.Object, mockHttpProvider.Object);
        User users = new User() 
        { 
            Id = "1", 
            DisplayName = "test",
            GivenName = "test2",
            Surname = "test3"
        };
        var emails = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        // setup the call
        mockGraphClient
          .Setup(g => g.Users
              .Request()
              .GetAsync(CancellationToken.None))
              .ReturnsAsync(users)
              .Verifiable(); 

        // Act
        var graphClient = mockGraphClient.Object;
        var user = graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        // Assert
        // Assert.AreEqual(users.Id, users.Id);
    }
```

Comment: You seem to mock the indexer on the Users Property but you don't use the indexer? Or just in the test but not in the real code but then with an empty indexer that shouldn't be allowed in the first place. You asked how to test GetUsersAsync from your class but actually test the graph client? Could you please clean up your question?

Comment: I edited it now. To clarify, I am trying to mock the graph api in order to test my repository method that call it. I have a repo interface, a repo that calls the graph api to get resources. I am trying to unit test that code.

Comment: I would recommend you to use strict mocks if possible. Currently you mock GetAsync with a CancellationToken i'm not sure if two CancellationToken.None(s) are equal so that the setup works? Maybe change it to `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()`. I assume you use Moq.